# Is A276175 integer-only?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, cluster-algebras

The terms of the sequence [A276123](https://oeis.org/A276123), defined by $a_0=a_1=a_2=1$ and $$a_n=\dfrac{(a_{n-1}+1)(a_{n-2}+1)}{a_{n-3}}\;,$$ are all integers (it's easy to prove that for all $n\geq2$, $a_n=\frac{9-3(-1)^n}{2}a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-1$).

But is it also true for the sequence [A276175](https://oeis.org/A276175) defined by $a_0=a_1=a_2=a_3=1$ and $$a_n=\dfrac{(a_{n-1}+1)(a_{n-2}+1)(a_{n-3}+1)}{a_{n-4}} \;\;?$$

**Remark** : This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905063/is-a276175-integer-only) ; one participant gave an interesting answer, but partial.

Comment: I feel that 'cluster algebras' tag may be appropriate.

Comment: When using generic $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$, one does not get Laurent polynomials (starting with $a_8$).

Comment: So it is unlikely 'cluster algebras'.

Comment: At least a priori it could be Laurent polynomial not literally in $a_0,\dots,a_3$, but in something different, like, say, also $(a_1a_2+1)/(a_2+a_3)$ or whatever.

Comment: @FedorPetrov they are actual polynomials in the first eight $a_{n-1}a_{n+1}/(a_n(a_n+1))$ but unfortunately for this particular sequence, those quantities are not all integers.

Comment: @darij grinberg : perhaps in view of today's edit it would be helpful to indicate why the MSE proof is not complete (I note that also OEIS lists this as a proven statement).

Comment: @FedorPetrov what's the connection with cluster algebras?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The proof relies on a computer calculation that no one but mercio seems to have seen let alone checked. And from the sound of his comments, mercio doesn't seem 100% sure of it either.

Comment: @YCor The first sequence (the one with the explicit quasi-linear recurrence) is one of the period-1 Laurent phenomenon sequences from Alman, Cuenca and Huang's paper, thus presumably related to cluster algebras (not sure about this).

Comment: Initially I thought all of the recurrences $a^{(k)}_n = \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (a^{(k)}_{n-i}+1)/a^{(k)}_{n-k}$ (with initial values all $1$) might have all terms integral - where $a^{(3)}$ is https://oeis.org/A276123 and $a^{(4)}$ is https://oeis.org/A276175.  But it seems that $a^{(6)}_{12}$ is non-integral.

Comment: More precisely, it seems that $a^{(5)}$ is still integral (checked for $n<35$), and $a^{(k)}$ is non-integral for $k>5$.