# A sequence potentially consisting of only integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences, oeis

I will first ask the question which can be stated very simply. Afterwards I will explain some motivation and give references to related sequences.

> Consider the sequence defined by
>   $$b_n = \frac{(b_{n-1} + 1)(b_{n-2} + 1)(b_{n-3} + 1)(b_{n-4}+1)}{b_{n-5}}$$
>   where $b_0 = b_1 = b_2 = b_3 = b_4 = 1$.
>
> **Question:** Is $b_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \geq 0$?
>
> Provided my program is correct, I have found that $b_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $0 \leq n \leq 36$.

I came to this thinking about [MO323867](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323867/integer-but-not-laurent-sequences) which asks for sequences that have all integer values but do not satisfy the [Laurent phenomenon](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104241).
More generally we can consider the sequence defined by

$$a^{(k)}_n = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (a^{(k)}_{n-i} + 1)}{a^{(k)}_{n-k}}$$

with $a_0 = a_1 = \cdots = a_{k-1} = 1$.

- When $k=2$ we obtain $a^{(2)}_n a^{(2)}_{n-2} = a^{(2)}_{n-1} + 1$ which can be seen coming from a type $A_2$ cluster algebra which implies the Laurent phenomenon and integrality (see [A076839](https://oeis.org/A076839)).
- When $k=3$ we have the Laurent phenomenon and hence the sequence is all integers (see [A276123](https://oeis.org/A276123)). The Laurent phenomenon follows for a more general result in Theorem 6.2.3 of the  [thesis of Matthew Russell](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/Theses/MatthewRussellThesis.pdf).
- When $k = 4$ the sequence does not exhibit the Laurent phenomenon, but it is still a sequence of integers (see [A276175](https://oeis.org/A276175), [MO248604](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248604/is-a276175-integer-only), [MSE1905063](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905063/is-a276175-integer-only)).
- When $k = 5$ we have the sequence from the question asked above.
- When $k > 5$ the sequence does not consist of only integers with the first violation being $a^{(k)}_{2k} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$.
  This can be seen by looking at the 2-adic valuation. In particular, it can be shown $\nu_2(a^{(k)}_{2k}) = 5-k$ for $k \geq 5$. To see this we can work $\pmod{2^5}$ and find that $(a^{(k)}_{2k-1} + 1) \equiv 2^4 \pmod{2^5}$. It is clear that $a_k = 2^{k-1}$ and $a_{n}$ is even, equivalently $(a_{n}+1)$ is odd, for $k \leq n < 2k - 1$.

So, the sequence $b_n$ corresponding to $k=5$ is the only sequence in the family which I do not know if all terms are integers.

Comment: The obvious Mathematica code (and an hour on my laptop) confirmed integrality up to $n=41$.

Comment: These numbers get big fast!  I noticed that the last digits seem to be always be 1 or 6.  Moreover, after some initial "noise," the repeating pattern is 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1 (starting at $n=11$).  Looking modulo 30, from the same point the repeating pattern is 16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1, 1.

Comment: I can't find a proof that for $k\ge5$, we have $(a^{(k)}_{2k-1} + 1) \equiv 2^4 \pmod{2^5}$. Would you give more hints? thanks!

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the computations. It's always nice to have additional verification. Brian, thanks for the interesting observation. @RenéGy for k=5 one can computer mod 32 and find 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 8, 4, 26, 15. For k>5 it will be an initial segment of 1s, followed by some 0s, followed by 16, 8, 4, 26, 15. Note the 0s don't really change things since we multiply by 0+1=1 in the recurrence.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced the $k=4$ case is really resolved.

Comment: @SamHopkins I agree with you. I have tried to look more at the accepted answer on Math.SE in hopes it would address this question too, but I have  not been able to completely follow it either.

Comment: I guess you know what a Somos sequences is - they are defined by somewhat similar recurrences, and also surprisingly consists of integers in some setups. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence. Maybe some methods from there can be used?

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora I do know of Somos sequences. This sequence does not have Laurentness like the Somos sequence. So, it seems to behave differently yet still have integrality.

Comment: but perhaps some other techniques applicable to Somos sequences can be used, but I am less familiar with such techniques.

Comment: Alright - I assumed you would know that, but I thought it may be reasonable to mention it just in case.

Comment: In a similar vein to the observation of @BrianHopkins, for $n=0$ through $n=35$ (which is as far as I can carry the calculations in Mathematica on my system) the residues of $b_n \bmod{20925}$ are 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 136, 9316, 136, 9316, 1, 11626, 1, 1, 1, 9316, 136, 16, 136, 9316, 1, 1, 1, 11626, 1, 9316, 136, 9316, 136, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16. If this apparent pattern persists, then $b_n \equiv b_{n-30} \equiv b_{34-n} \bmod{20925}$.